# R equivalent of a SQL UPDATE query

Tags: sql, r

I want to do the equivalent of an UPDATE query in SQL using R.  If I have data like this:

```
# Example Data
df <- data.frame(x <- c("My Name", "My Name"), y <- c("AZ", "MI"))
colnames(df) <- c("Name", "State")

print(df)

> print(df)
     Name State
1 My Name    AZ
2 My Name    MI
```

I'd like to do the R equivalent of this in SQL :

```
update df
set Name = 'My Name1' 
where Name = 'My Name' 
and State = 'MI
```

So the final output is:

```
> print(df)
      Name State
1  My Name    AZ
2 My Name1    MI
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Because you're using factors in your data frame, you are going to need to change the factor levels first using

```
levels(df$Name) <- c(levels(df$Name), "My Name1")
```

before actually changing the data frame using

```
df[df$Name == "My Name" & df$State == "MI", "Name"] <- "My Name1"
```

Comment: In R you can also directly reference the 'cells' with `df[2,1] <- "My Name1"` You can also bypass the factor issue by using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in `data.frame()`

Comment: True, but in referencing the cells you loose the analog to the SQL commands, so for large databases that doesn't always work.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is:

`df[logical condition OR rownumbers, column name or number] <- assignment`

So you could do:

```
df[df$Name == "MyName" & df$State == "MI", "State"] <- "My Name1"
```

Comment: That doesn't work (even if I edit df$Name == "MyName" to df$Name == "My Name"). Am I missing something?